# Move The Angle Of

Tags: word-usage

I have a question about a usage involving the verb "*move*" and the noun "*angle*" [here](http://quest.arc.nasa.gov/space/frontiers/activities/aeronautics/a.html):

> Now imagine you are on a roller coaster, and you are holding your hand out, just like you did in the car example, but, this time, don't ***move the angle of your hand***.

Is "***move*** *the* ***angle*** *of your hand*" weird sounding?  Would "***change*** *the* ***angle*** *of your hand*" be better?

Comment: Changing the angle definitely sounds more correct. or you can just use "don't move your hand".

Answer (score 1):

> Now imagine you are on a roller coaster, and you are holding your hand out, just like you did in the car example, but, this time, ***don't move the angle of your hand.***

This example is both grammatical and idiomatic, although I agree that your suggestion to replace **"move"** with **"change"** is an improvement to the sentence, as long as it does not distort the meaning within its larger context. Is this example from a physics problem? I'm just wondering why the original author chose "move" to begin with.

Comment: So, "move the angle of" is indeed poorly written?

Comment: It could be perfectly written, it really depends on what you are talking about!  The way it is currently reading makes it sound very intricate.  You may or may not want that.